# Como mostrar um loader enquanto processa uma função javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, radiobutton

Tenho um botão radio que quando clicado, executa uma função que monta um datepicker.

Porém a função mountDatepicker só é carregada depois de alguns segundos, após fazer a consulta a três apis para então montar o calendário.

Então como faço para carregar uma imagem com um loader no lugar do calendário enquanto a função não termina?

```
$("input[type='radio']").click(function(){
    if ($("input[name='diasaluguel']:checked").length > 0 ) {

    mountDatepicker();

    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function addLoader(el) {
    var gif = 'http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-Atj4ze_I-84/UeJk-CPeCsI/AAAAAAAAHno/UIbSZkTfWBA/s1600/loading.gif';
    var img = document.createElement('img');
    img.src = gif;
    el.innerHTML = '';
    el.appendChild(img);
}
```

Cria uma função para ser corrida antes do mountDatepicker(); ser chamado. Podes fazer isso de maneira diferente: como eu sugiro, ou já tendo no HTML uma div que se sobrepõe à do calendário.

Como eu fiz ele adiciona um elemento `img` ao calendário e depois remove.

#### Exemplo: http://jsfiddle.net/Sergio_fiddle/uxL5h57w/